# redirect the output of a command to a new file in an existing tar

Tags: linux, shell, tar

I wondering how to redirect output of a command (eg. 'dpkg --get-selections | grep deinstall | cut -f1') to a new file in an existing tar file.

Comment: Is there a reason why you wouldn't just redirect output of your command to a file and then append it to tape archive with `-r`?

Comment: I just want to avoid to use an intermediate file (if possible)

Answer (score 0):

This is unfortunately not possible, because if we were to specify a FIFO as a file to store to the archive, `tar` would store the named pipe, but not the data written to it, and the archive would contain something like

```
prw------- armali/504        0 2016-09-21 10:21:23 dev/fd/63
```